# How to render templates to multiple layouts in Go?

Tags: go, go-templates

I need to render templates into different kinds of layout. Here's my directory structure.

```
myapp
|
│   main.go
│
├───static
│       script.js
│       style.css
│
└───templates
    │   page1.tmpl
    │   page2.tmpl
    │   page3.tmpl
    │   page4.tmpl
    │   page5.tmpl
    │
    └───layouts
            base1.tmpl
            base2.tmpl
            base3.tmpl
```

I have done rendering templates to a single layout template but, I can't make it work on multiple layouts. Here's what I got so far:

```
package main

import (
    "html/template"
    "net/http"
    "fmt"
    "github.com/urfave/negroni"
    "github.com/oxtoacart/bpool"
    "path/filepath"
    "log"
)

var (
    templates        map[string]*template.Template
    bufpool          *bpool.BufferPool
)

func main() {
    loadTemplates()
    mux := http.NewServeMux()
    mux.HandleFunc("/", func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        renderTemplate(w, "page1.tmpl",nil)
    })
    n := negroni.New()
    n.Use(negroni.NewLogger())
    n.UseHandler(mux)
    http.ListenAndServe(":8080", n)
}

func renderTemplate(w http.ResponseWriter, name string, data map[string]interface{}) error {
    tmpl, ok := templates[name]
    if !ok {
        return fmt.Errorf("The template %s does not exist.", name)
    }

    buf := bufpool.Get()
    defer bufpool.Put(buf)

    err := tmpl.ExecuteTemplate(buf, "base1.tmpl", data)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }

    w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "text/html; charset=utf-8")
    buf.WriteTo(w)
    return nil
}

func loadTemplates() {
    if templates == nil {
        templates = make(map[string]*template.Template)
    }

    tmplDir := "templates/"

    layouts, err := filepath.Glob(tmplDir + "layouts/*.tmpl")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    includes, err := filepath.Glob(tmplDir + "*.tmpl")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    for _, include := range includes {
        files := append(layouts, include)
        templates[filepath.Base(include)] = template.Must(template.ParseFiles(files...))
    }
    fmt.Print(includes)
    bufpool = bpool.NewBufferPool(64)
}
```

Here's how `base1.tmpl` looks like:

```
{{define "base1"}}
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>{{block "title" .}}{{end}}</title>
</head>
<body>
{{template "content" .}}
</body>
</html>
{{end}}
```

And here's how `page1.tmpl` looks like:

```
{{define "title"}}Page 1{{end}}

{{define "content"}}
<p>Page 1 contents</p>
{{end}}
```

Comment: What do your templates look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I normally take the approach of rendering twice, once for content, once for layout, this lets you use any content in any layout and defer that decision till runtime. Would be interested in other approaches if other people do it differently, but this is working for me at present.

So using the code you have posted, something like this in handler:

```
data := map[string]interface{}{
            "title": "hello world",
        }
renderTemplate(w, "base1.tmpl", "page1.tmpl", data)
```

...

in renderTemplate pass in a layout as well as a template and:

```
// Render the template 'name' with data
buf := bufpool.Get()
err := tmpl.ExecuteTemplate(buf, name, data)
if err != nil {
    return err
}

// Set the content as a key on data (set as html as it is rendered)
data["content"] = template.HTML(buf.Bytes())
bufpool.Put(buf)

// Render the layout 'layout' with data, using template as content key
buf = bufpool.Get()
defer bufpool.Put(buf)  
err = tmpl.ExecuteTemplate(buf, layout, data)
if err != nil {
    return err
}
```

Layout:

```
<html>
<body>
   <h1>Base 1</h1>
   {{.content}}
</body>
</html>
```

Page:

```
<h2>{{.title}}</h2>
<h3>Page 1</h3>
```

Here is a link to full code:

https://play.golang.org/p/R2vr4keZec

Comment: I tried this but, I get a empty response. Kindly recheck my post, I added the contents of my templates Sir. Thanks

Comment: Remove all the {{define "xxx"}}{{end}}, and leave the content, you don't need to define templates if you load them all in the template set with distinct names, you can use those names to refer to them. If you only define, and never *use* blocks, you'll render a blank template, it's unfortunate they introduced this blocks feature IMO as it just makes templates more confusing. I've added an example template.

Comment: It works now. Thank you for making me understand how it works @Kenny Grant.